# Relaunch Finder link missing

Tags: macos, finder

I recently needed to show hidden files in my iMac 2011 and had to relaunch Finder to do so. Every tutorial I saw, said to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click on the Finder icon and then click "relaunch". The trouble is: I don't have this link.

In the end I went to the Apple menu in the top left, and Force quit Finder, which had the same effect.

Does anybody else not have the relaunch button? Is there a problem with my Mac?

Comment: I edited the answer, but you have to alt + ctrl left click or alt right click to display "Relaunch". I verified this in OSX 10.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relaunch option is at the bottom of the pop-up menu you get when you <kbd>alt</kbd> right-click (or <kbd>Control</kbd> +<kbd>alt</kbd> left click) the Finder icon in the Dock.

Comment: Sorry I've just tried that and Cmd-click only opens a new window. I think you need to ctrl+click to get the pop up menu. I do get a popup menu but no "relaunch" link. I tried to post a picture to show you the problem, but I don't have enough rep unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I had the alt/opt key pressed while trying it but didn't realize it at the time. So much for muscle memory.